# Kohana 3. Модуль авторизация:Не работаеть login,logout

Tags: php, kohana

Начал изучать kohana 3 по видеокурсу Морковина. Дошел до Auth.
Тестирую модуль авторизаций Auth,через ORM (через driver=file все работаеть) при

авторизаций, получаю вот такую ошибку:

[image]

Что я делаю не так? Все как в видеокурсе делаю.

[image]
Вот контроллер:

```
public function action_index()
    {   

        $auth = Auth::instance();

        if ( $auth->logged_in()) 
        {
            $data["message"] = "Logged!";
        }

        else  

        {
            $data["message"] = "Not Logged!";
        }

        if ( isset( $_POST['btn_log']) )

        {
            $login = Arr::get($_POST,'login','');
            $password = Arr::get($_POST,'password','');

            $auth->login($login,$password);

        }

        $this->template->content = View::factory('home', $data);
    }

    public function action_hashpass()
    {
        $auth = Auth::instance();

        $this->template->content = $auth->hash_password('admin');
    }
        public function action_logout()
    {
        $auth = Auth::instance();
        $auth->logout();

            $data["message"] = "We loged out!!";


        $this->template->content=View::factory('home', $data);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы используете Denwer? Из скриншота - видно, что Denwer. На Денвере работать не будет!!!

Ставьте отдельно Apache + MySQL + PHP + Kohana и будет все отлично работать! Проверено Zanussi)))

И запомните - Денвер это ЗЛО)

[Видео от Морковина - Как настроить Apache + MySQL + PHP](http://www.sdelaysite.com/php/php-2)

Answer (score 1):

> driver=file

я не помню точно, на kohana давно писал, по-моему нужно driver=orm указывать...